# Making specific words clickable in android using SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: java, android

I want to make some words clickable in a given string like " I have to meet @vikash and @walker and also @jay. (onClick i will open a dialer window.)
In this i want to make all words clickable that are having "@" in starting. 
using this there is only one word is clickable.

```
private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePart(String str) {
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(str);

    int idx1 = desc.indexOf("@");
    int idx2 = 0;
    while (idx1 != -1) {
        idx2 = str.indexOf(" ", idx1) + 1;

        final String clickString = str.substring(idx1, idx2);
        ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Toast.makeText(ViewNote.this, clickString,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, idx1, idx2, 0);
        idx1 = str.indexOf("[", idx2);
    }

    return ssb;

}
```

Comment: how many spans do you have?

Comment: in app user can save many @contacts.

Comment: `idx1 = str.indexOf("[", idx2);` should be `idx1 = str.indexOf("@", idx2);`

Comment: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: @Blackbelt

Comment: also index2 could be negative. In your example you have `also @jay.` `idx1` is the index of `@`, but from that index you don't have an empty space and idx2 should be negative

Comment: I want only words that having @abc not any other words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Veaceslav Gaidarji say, for @ words try using [regex](https://www.regex101.com/r/cT2qF8/2).

Try this piece of code:

```
private SpannableString addClickablePart(String str) {
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(str);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[@]\\w*");
    Pattern matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
      ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            // do toasting
        }
      };
      ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, matcher.start, matcher.end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    return ss;
}
```

--- Edited ---

this code will search for all @character by using regex pattern ([@]\w*), then add clickable span to them.
We use SpannableString instead SpannableStringBuilder because we don't need building a spannableString here.

Comment: didn't get which string should be append on  textview?

Comment: add description please Juan.

Comment: Bravo!! Worked finely. Thanks

Comment: its working its working any where i clicks on @abc. what if i need separate click. because i have to go a dialer activity on click on a contact. so i have to handle separate clicks.

Comment: how can make separate clicks for every @abc and if this is not possible than please tell me how can i get only clicked string. not whole string that starting from "@".

Answer (score 0):

You should create custom link rules for your `TextView` as described [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html). In your case, you need regex which will find all words starting with `@` character ([sample](https://www.regex101.com/r/cT2qF8/2) regex).

Comment: would you please relate my case? please. i am just a newbie.